# Importing Image into Android Studio, image appears as dark grey

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302854/importing-image-into-android-studio-appears-as-dark-grey) person faced, but the answer he gave there did not solve my problem.

If I Right Click on drawable and then navigate to -> New -> Image Asset, and follow the steps and select my icon location, it places the images in the drawable folder, with the hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi sizes.  However, if I view/use the icons, they appear as grey blocks, which have the shape of the image, but no color. Here is an image:

[image]

If I copy the Image, and Right Click drawable -> Paste, it pastes the images, and color is back, but does not get set in the different sizes. Here is an image:

[image]

I have inserted images before using the first approach, and never had this problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think, possibly, that your image has layers and only the shadow layer (the shadow) is being utilized when you import. Complete guess, but only thing I could imagine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right Click on drawable-> navigate to -> New -> Batch Drawable Import-> fClick on the + sign. Choose your image and click OK. It will create the images with different density.

For enabling the Android Drawable Importer plugin you can refer this link http://www.javahelps.com/2015/02/android-drawable-importer.html

Comment: I will give this a try when I get back home, and mark as accepted if it worked for me. Thanks